# Problem: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash

I have  some code in `HomeViewController`. When I open next controller and tap the button and do

```
let strotyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Anketa", bundle: nil)
    if let anketaController = strotyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QuestionnaireViewController") as? QuestionnaireViewController {
        anketaController.startNew = true
        print("1111 HomeViewController openNext , ", anketaController)
        present(anketaController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

When I back to `HomeViewController` and tap the button again to open `QuestionnaireViewController` it was an error message:

> "QuestionnaireViewController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x10480a400"

I printed - `print("1111 HomeViewController openNext , ", anketaController)` and first time I tapped the button it was:

```
1111 HomeViewController openNext ,  <.QuestionnaireViewController: 0x10480a400>
```

on the second tapped button it was:

```
1111 HomeViewController openNext ,  <.QuestionnaireViewController: 0x10901fa00>
```

and the app crashes on iOS 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omer's answer is probably right. I have a lot of trouble with creating retain cycles myself (even after quite a lot of time). What helped me was [this idea of doing an extension to UIViewController that makes a delayed check on the self pointer to make sure it's deallocated](https://holko.pl/2017/06/26/checking-uiviewcontroller-deallocation/).

If your view controller is not deallocated after 2 seconds, you're sure to have a leak so you the assert will stop your code and you can use the Memory Graph feature of XCode, find your view controller and see what's keeping it alive.